# Can we use javascript expressions in th:if in thymleaf?

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have created a dynamic select dropdown list and in another div i wanted to use the selected value to compare it with string to display a div. But i am not getting the selected value (brandId) instead getting value already saved in database. I am new to thymeleaf and springboot so maybe i am missing out something. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Through this i am getting value in temp but how to use this temp in place of brandId?

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
  /*<![CDATA[*/
   
    function getSelectedRegion(){
        var temp= document.getElementById('brandId').value;
        return alert(temp);

    }
   /*]]>*/
```

```
                    <div class="select-brand-dropdown">
                        <label th:text="#{brand}"></label> *
            
                        <select class="form-control" th:field="*{brandId}">
                            <option th:each="brand : ${brands}" th:value="${brand.id}"
                                th:utext="${brand.label}" />
                        </select>
                    </div>

           <div th:if="${market=='m1'} and *{brandId=='b1'} or ${market=='m2'} and *{brandId=='b1'} ">
              <p>VALID BRAND and MARKET</p>
           </div>
```

Comment: Thymeleaf is rendered on the server and then sent to the browser. JavaScript runs in the browser _after_ the rendering is done.

Comment: So how can i get the selected value?